# Getting IssuerName certificate don't expect like require in xades xml document

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to sign an xml document with xades in c#, and when I am sending the information the web service is returning:

> "com.indra.mmdd.signature.exceptions.ValidateException: xades4j.verification.CertRefUtils$1: Verification failed for property 'SigningCertificate': Invalid issue name: C=CO, L=Bogota D.C., O=Andes SCD., OU=Division de certificacion entidad final, CN=CA ANDES SCD S.A. Clase II, E=info@andesscd.com.co".

Which I think is due to the SigningCertificate tag is being produced like:

```
<X509IssuerName>
C=CO, L=Bogota D.C., O=Andes SCD., OU=Division de certificacion entidad final, CN=CA ANDES SCD S.A. Clase II, E=info@andesscd.com.co
</X509IssuerName>
<X509SerialNumber>6269250364567719715</X509SerialNumber>
```

But the web service is expecting something more like:

```
<xades:IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>
C=CO,L=Bogota D.C.,O=Andes SCD.,OU=Division de certificacion entidad final,CN=CA ANDES SCD S.A. Clase II,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1614696e666f40616e6465737363642e636f6d2e636f
</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>9128602840918470673</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</xades:IssuerSerial>
```

Why am I getting a different IssuerName? I am Using

```
x509IssuerName.InnerText = signingCertificate.Issuer;
```

How Can I produced the required IssuerName?

Comment: The missing ds is a namespace that is a missing attribute in you xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time searching I found that the difference is the representation of the email info, while in the first it is represented with que 'E' the second one use the OID description (1.2.840.113549.1.9.1), in the other hand "info@andesscd.com.co" is encoded in asn.1 which is represented as "1614696e666f40616e6465737363642e636f6d2e636f".

I didn't find any way of doing it through any class, so I did it manually, for the encoding in asn.1 I searched for a library.